# Exporting large data from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I have a mosaic of Sentinel-2 images for the city of Porto (in Portugal). I have done all the initial image processing in GEE (python) and now want to use it outside of GEE so I can use the data to train some models.

While I know that GEE was not made to download large amounts of data, I still want to try to see if it is possible to export this type of images. I have 'resampled' all bands to 10 meters and added some new bands which made the image even bigger.

I have tried several ways to download the image. The first using two methods from the [geemap](https://geemap.org/), the *[download_ee_image](https://geemap.org/common/?h=download_ee_image#geemap.common.download_ee_image)* and *[download_ee_image_tiles](https://geemap.org/common/?h=download_ee_image#geemap.common.download_ee_image_tiles)*. This is taking too much time, and while I am working with this AOI at the moment in the future I would like to increase it and I am not sure it would be possible since I already gotten some

> **Error downloading tile: User memory limit exceeded.**

.
For example, using the piece of code below for the district of Porto it took me **180 minutes** to download the image in tiles.

```py
features = geemap.fishnet(AOI, rows=3, cols=4)
geemap.download_ee_image_tiles(
    image, features, out_dir="output", prefix="image_", crs=CRS, scale=10
)
```

I also found these two posts [1](https://mygeoblog.com/2019/08/21/google-earth-engine-to-numpy/) and [2](https://mygeoblog.com/2019/08/21/google-earth-engine-to-numpy/) where the idea would be to export my image to a numpy array and then convert it to a geotiff. However when I try to run the code I get stuck on this part with the code not being able to get over this line:

```py
data = np.array((ee.Array(latlon.get("B2")).getInfo())) #all bands crash
```

I am now trying another approach. Using the [export to asset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-toasset) method like seen bellow. However the task has started for quite some time now and I still haven't gotten the image in the asset.

```py
# If the export has more than 1e8 pixels, set "maxPixels" higher.
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(
    image=image,
    description='image',
    assetId='projects/<project>/assets/<asset_id>',
    region=AOI,
    scale=10,
    crs=CRS,
    maxPixels=1e13
)
task.start()
```

Is there another approach to this that I could try?

I want to maintain the scale of 10 and I would like to be able to guarantee that if I try this with a bigger area that it is possible to extract the image from GEE.